# Querying Domain Controller objects using Powershell

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

Could someone explain to me why this does not work?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$dcs = Get-ADComputer -Filter {DistinguishedName -Like "*Domain Controllers*"}
```

I get no results for this query.

Alternatively, could someone suggest a way using the module above that I can generate a list of systems on my domain that are NOT Domain Controllers (which is what I'm eventually trying to achieve).

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. -like operator doesn't work with all properties. It doesn't work with DistinguishedName, SID, ObjectClass, but it works with Name, DSNHostName, SamAccountName...

The following command will give you all domain controllers:

PS C:> Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Domain Controllers,DC=test,DC=local" -Filter *

This command will give you all computers that are NOT domain controllers:

PS C:> Get-ADComputer -LDAPfilter "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))"

Answer (score 0):

As all Domain Controllers should end up in the "Domain Controller" OU in AD when you promote the server, why not try:

```
$dcs = Get-ADComputer -SearchRoot "MYDOMAIN/Domain Controllers" -SearchScope onelevel
```

I think this is what you were trying to do above. Also be aware this is not a definitive way to find a Domain controller. Ideally you should search by member type.

```
$dcs = get-ADComputer -SearchRoot "MYDOMAIN" -SearchScope subtree -filter {ComputerRole -eq "DomainController" }
```

That should find any wayward DC's :)

As an aside, I unsuccessfully spent 30 mins trying to get the AD Module installed - its apparently a "New in 2008 R2" thing, and is a complete PITA if you don't have a 2008R2 machine handy :) I've used Quest AD Management Tools to devise the answer - the arguments are the same...